# Plasmid gene knockout

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology

How do delete a single gene encoded in an operon on a plasmid using E. coli? Could you use the same principle as when knocking out a gene from the bacterial chromosome which is e.g. suicide vector-derived allelic replacement through homologous recombination?

Thanks for your response.

Comment: So you have a plasmid and you want to delete a section? Why not do the deletion outside the cell with PCR or something and then transform into new cells?

Answer (score 1):

Well the simplest way is to cut the gene at the both ends from operon by means of proper restriction enzymes but in case that you get more than one recognition site then you can use microRNA or proper oligo to make a hairpin loop and break that part 
If you only want to silence the operon then you just need to cut it nearly at middle of the gene and ligate it with a nonsense sequence, then it will loose it's functionality.